# Android minifyEnabled = true shrinkResources = true keep crashing application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

getting below exception in Google Play Publish website. If i minifyEnabled false shrinkResources = false. application working fine.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: MyApp, PID: 27778
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MyApp/MyApp.GridLayoutActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:166)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:158)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:34)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:77)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.a(MotionEvents.java:52)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.c(Tap.java:8)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap.b(Tap.java:18)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:3)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:96)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

proguard-rules.pro  - I added some keep but still not working

```
-keepclassmembers class android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView {
    boolean mShiftingMode;
}
-keep class com.shockwave.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.**  { *; }
-keep class com.baseflow.permissionhandler.**  { *; }
```

build.gradle  - I tried using minifyEnabled false and shrinkResources false then its working fine.

```
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'MyApp'
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 36
        versionName "0.81"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.BethakjiAppSign
            android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.all {
                    outputFileName = "${applicationId}.apk"
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are want to use  minifyEnabled=true shrinkResources = true please write proper proguard.

Comment: Please share your `build.gradle` and `proguard-rules.pro` files.

Comment: build.gradle and proguard-rules.pro updated.

Comment: Create a signed APK/Bundle and test locally too, it's most likely a proguard issue or R8.

Comment: Its working fine locally while debugging. its only failed after uploading it on google play.

Comment: I had the same experience with minifyEnabled true. For me it has nothing to do with proguard. Actually with useProguard true the size of the app is about the same as minifyEnabled, but the app works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add rules for `java.lang` in proguard. Something like this:

```
-keep class java.lang.** { *; }
```

It works in debug mode because the application is not signed with the release certificate. You can test release build before publish if you run release flavor from Android Studio. In this way, application will be signed and you can run it on your device and go through application. Probably you need to add more rules to the proguard depending on the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your /proguard-rules.pro to this.

```
#Flutter Wrapper
 -keep class com.shockwave.**
 -keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
 -keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

and in /android/app/build.gradle add this.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources false
        useProguard true 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```